# Is possible to secure communication between Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine?

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I deployed an app with nodejs on Google App Engine and mongodb on Compute Engine.
Without security rules, GAE can successfully connect to mongodb, but when I set a security rule which allow to access port 27017 of the VM from the App Engine service account I get timeout request so mongodb is not reachable.

As is not possible to set a static ip to GAE, is there another solution to securing mongodb on Compute Engine?

Answer (score 0):

Check the priority of firewall allow rule and deny rule. Lower numbers have higher priorities. Be sure that the allow firewall rule has a higher priority than other rules that might deny traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the moment you're not able to set a static external IP on your GAE application.

**There's a possible workaround for GAE Flex to solve your issue**:

1. [reserve](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) an external static IP
2. [create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) `f1-micro` VM instance with reserved external IP address (this likely fits in the Compute Engine [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier))
3. [create](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) a firewall rule to allow connection to MongoDB server from reserved external IP
4. create a SOCKS proxy by running a ssh client that routes the traffic through created VM similar to this [example](https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-static-ip/)
5. configure nodejs application to use SOCKS Proxy
6. connect to MongoDB server

**UPDATE**

Also, if you application can run over HTTP proxy you can [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) proxy installed on this VM instead of SOCKS Proxy.

Comment: Thanks Serhii to point me to the right direction.
Actually for me is impossible to use the serverless vpc access as it can be deployed only on a subset of supported region.
For App Engine Flex there is no need to configure a serverless vpc as described here (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) "Note: If you want to use internal IP addresses when connecting from the App Engine flexible environment, you don't need to configure Serverless VPC Access. Just make sure your App Engine flexible environment VMs are located in the same VPC network...".

Comment: Update your answer for the flex one and after I tested it I'll accept your answer

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer. Please try to follow my instruction.

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. For the standard you can use the vpc serverless, but for the flex there is no need of the workaround as they are in the same network and is possible to use the internal ip

Comment: Two days ago I removed from my answer any mention of GAE Standard and VPC Serverless. As a solution for GAE Flex I suggested to use some separate VM as a proxy with step by step instruction. Probably you still see some cached version of this page, [here](https://ibb.co/tsZ5DKd) you can screenshot of my answer.